# Type-cast `float` to `str` without losing precision

Tags: python, string, list

I am quite new to Python, and have a list like the following:

```
[{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:39:00'},
{u'value': 0.019179999828338623, u'time': u'12:40:00'},
{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:41:00'},
{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:42:00'},
{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:43:00'},
{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:44:00'},
{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:45:00'},
{u'value': 0, u'time': u'12:46:00'},
{u'value': 0.01713000051677227, u'time': u'12:47:00'},
{u'value': 0.023979999125003815, u'time': u'12:48:00'}]
```

I pass this list to a different function that is supposed to format it to a certain way (remove all elements where the value is 0, and add date to the time element). As an example, I am trying to achieve the following "cleaned list":

```
[{'count': '0.019179999828338623', 'datetime': '2016-12-11 12:40:00'}, ...]
```

The problem I am facing is that when I iterate over all elements in the list, Python seems to be truncating the value to 15 characters, so the above turns out to be:

```
[{'count': '0.0191799998283', 'datetime': '2016-12-11 12:40:00'}, ...]
```

My code to "clean" the list is as follows

```
for my_data in my_list:
    if my_data['value']:
            my_record = {"count": str(my_data['value']), "datetime": '%s %s' % (the_date, my_data['time'])}
            final_result.append(my_record)
```

I have tried printing my_list from this function - the data is properly there (without the truncation). But, when I print the current element from within the loop (`print(my_data['value'])`), I get the 15-character-truncated value.

Any help shall be appreciated!

Comment: @Kundor: Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of type-casting it to [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) instead. You will get the value as string without losing precision. For example:

```
>>> repr(0.019179999828338623)
'0.019179999828338623'
```

Hence your code should be like:

```
for my_data in my_list:
    if my_data['value']:
        final_result.append({
            "count": repr(my_data['value']),  # Using `repr` here
            "datetime": '%s %s' % (the_date, my_data['time'])
        })
```